# Need to parse a file and create a data structure out of it

Tags: python, list, data-structures, readlines, fileparse

We want to parse a file and create a data structure of some sort to be used later (in Python).
The content of file looks like this:

```
plan HELLO
   feature A 
       measure X :
          src = "Type ,N ame"
       endmeasure //X

       measure Y :
        src = "Type ,N ame"
       endmeasure //Y

       feature Aa
           measure AaX :
              src = "Type ,N ame"
           endmeasure //AaX

           measure AaY :
              src = "Type ,N ame"
           endmeasure //AaY
           
           feature Aab
              .....
           endfeature // Aab
         
       endfeature //Aa
 
   endfeature // A
   
   feature B
     ......
   endfeature //B
endplan

plan HOLA
endplan //HOLA
```

So there's a file that contain one or more plans and then each plan contains one or more feature,
further each feature contains a measure that contains info (src, type, name) and feature can further contain more features.

We need to parse through the file and create a data structure that would have

```
                     plan (HELLO) 
            ------------------------------
             ↓                          ↓ 
          Feature A                  Feature B
  ----------------------------          ↓
   ↓           ↓             ↓           ........
Measure X    Measure Y    Feature Aa
                         ------------------------------
                            ↓           ↓             ↓ 
                       Measure AaX   Measure AaY   Feature Aab
                                                        ↓
                                                        .......
```

I am trying to parse through the file line by line and create a list of lists that would contain
plan -> feature -> measure, feature

Comment: Questions here should show what you've tried already first so we can improve your current solution.

Comment: this feels like something pyparsing would be good for ...

Comment: But as a starter, you can open a text file in python with `with open(file_path, 'r') as f: lines = f.read_lines()`. Then you can iterate over the lines in a for loop.

Comment: You really don't want to write and maintain your own parser if you can avoid it. Could whatever produces these files be persuaded to output in a standard machine-readable format like JSON, YAML, or XML?

Comment: You will have to build a custom parser here. Not very complex, but one major source of problems is the lexical part: can keywords (feature, endfeature, etc.) appear inside quoted strings? And can quoted strings contain quotes with a specific syntax? If the answer is yes, you really have to carefully detect the beginning and end of quoted strings before analyzing anything else. Tools like pyparsing or PLY could help here. Of course, if the syntax is much simpler (only a limited set of elements in strings and nothing close to keywords) you can build the parser *by hand*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that would turn your string into a dictionary:

```
def getplans(s):
    stack = [{}]
    for line in s.splitlines():
        if "=" in line:  # leaf
            key, value = line.split("=", 1)
            stack[-1][key.strip()] = value.strip(' "')
        elif line.strip()[:3] == "end":
            stack.pop()
        elif line.strip():
            collection, name, *_ = line.split()
            stack.append({})
            stack[-2].setdefault(collection + "s", {})[name] = stack[-1]
    return stack[0]
```

Here is an example call:

```
s = """plan HELLO
   feature A 
       measure X :
          src = "Type, Name"
       endmeasure //X

       measure Y :
        src = "Type, Name"
       endmeasure //Y

       feature Aa
           measure AaX :
              src = "Type, Name"
           endmeasure //AaX

           measure AaY :
              src = "Type, Name"
           endmeasure //AaY
           
           feature Aab
                measure Car :
                  src = "Model, Make"
               endmeasure //car
           endfeature // Aab
         
       endfeature //Aa
 
   endfeature // A
   
   feature B
       measure Hotel :
          src = "Stars, Reviews"
       endmeasure //Hotel
    endfeature //B
endplan

plan HOLA
endplan //HOLA
"""

import json
print(json.dumps(getplans(s), indent=4))
```

The output:

```
{
    "plans": {
        "HELLO": {
            "features": {
                "A": {
                    "measures": {
                        "X": {
                            "src": "Type ,N ame"
                        },
                        "Y": {
                            "src": "Type ,N ame"
                        }
                    },
                    "features": {
                        "Aa": {
                            "measures": {
                                "AaX": {
                                    "src": "Type ,N ame"
                                },
                                "AaY": {
                                    "src": "Type ,N ame"
                                }
                            },
                            "features": {
                                "Aab": {
                                    "measures": {
                                        "Car": {
                                            "src": "Model, Make"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "B": {
                    "measures": {
                        "Hotel": {
                            "src": "Stars, Reviews"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "HOLA": {}
    }
}
```

If your input has some other syntax -- not included in your question -- you'll probably need to tune the script further to deal with that.

Comment: can you provide some idea If there are more than one measures for example.  measure AaY :
              src = "Type, Name"                                                                                                      
                        "Type, Name2"                                                                                                       
                        "Type,Name3".  ....
 endmeasure //AaY

Comment: You should then check whether `stack[-2].setdefault(collection + "s", {})[name]` already exists before you assign to it. If it exists, then instead of the assignment, accumulate the `src` strings in a list. If you cannot make it work, then maybe present your attempt in a new question.

Comment: can you check here , i am losing some data with this approach at the end https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77232363/parse-a-file-and-create-a-data-structure

Answer (score -1):

For a quick and dirty parsing, you can do some regex substitutions, e.g.

```
text = re.sub(
    r'(?mx)^ \s* (plan|feature|measure) \s+ (\w+) .*',
    r'<\1 name="\2">',
    text)
text = re.sub(
    r'(?mx)^ \s* end (plan|feature|measure) .*',
    r'</\1>',
    text)
text = re.sub(
    r'(?mx)^ \s* (\w+) \s*=\s* (.*)',
    r'<\1>\2</\1>',
    text)
```

This will convert it to XML, which you can parse with built-in tools, e.g. ETree.